# heroku - rails - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

```
heroku create
Creating floating-planet-1824......................... done, stack is bamboo-mri-1.9.2
http://floating-planet-1824.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:floating-planet-1824.git

git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.156' to the list of known hosts.
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I generated ssh keys ok.

Rebooting didn't help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turned out that

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

worked.

Answer (score 20):

this is how i solved mine

```
$ heroku keys:clear
Removing all SSH keys... done
$ heroku login
```

after clearing all previous ssh. `heroku login`'s uploads back my ssh public key and i can happily `git push heroku master` back

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you already have a public and a private key to use in your `~/.ssh` folder, there might be two different scenarios:

- You didn't upload your **public key** to Heroku's remote server. Solution, execute: `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/your_public_key`
- Or you did, but you don't have your identities loaded into your SSH authentication agent. Solution, execute:

  `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/your_private_key # OSX`

  `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/your_private_key # Ubuntu`

and enter your passphrase, so you can use your **private key**.

Comment: Updated answer to show that the `-k` / `-K` option depends on OS.

Comment: Thanks!, I only had a Mac to test it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem which i face was setting the ssh environment variable.

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0

heroku keys
```

will show the keys, remove and then login, it will create one for you and add to your app.
Or you can create your rsa key with your email and then use it using

`heroku keys:add /path`

Generate key using 
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"`

Answer (score 0):

In case others are facing the same problem: using [standalone toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone) on fedora 16-17 with rmv 1.17.3 and system ruby 1.9.3p392, just clearing heroku keys and credentials was not sufficient, and I tested that the issue was not with my ssh keychain.  If anyone has faced similar issues, and is more familiar with the heroku toolbelt, I posted a [new issue here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/735).